# Doctrine Join entity with native Query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I want join with Left Join an Entity in native Query (ResultSetMappingBuilder) but the fonction addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata() need relation ...

```
addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata( string $class, string $alias, string $parentAlias, object $relation)
```

But I don't have relation : I want just join table without relation because is not bi-directional relation in entities. Ideally, in return, I want create a field containing the attached entity. :)

Comment: This seems like something you can do with regular doctrine association mapping?

You're not required to specify bi-directional associations.

See doctrine docs [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)